# Windows Task Scheduler - existing task modification c++

Tags: c++, windows, task, scheduled-tasks

How to modify programmatically existing scheduled task with API 2.0?
For example to add a trigger or an action.

Thanks.

Comment: See [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa446886(v=vs.85)), which creates a task in the root folder to send an email when triggered by an event.

Comment: @eryksun Already saw all the examples, however all of them create a new task and don't change existing one.

Comment: Open the task folder, get the task, and get its [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-itaskdefinition). Here's the [list of interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-2-0-interfaces).

Comment: @eryksun Thanks, that's what I was looking for!

Comment: Can you answer the question with a basic example in C++?